# Dropped iPhone 7 Plus - Screen no longer detected

Tags: iphone, unlock, touch-id, touchscreen

I dropped my iPhone 7 Plus and it no longer detects the screen. I say "no longer **detects**" because I confirmed it; I connected it to a monitor with an HDMI dongle and it sees the monitor as the only screen (screen fills the whole monitor and isn't stretched at all). I didn't do a backup for a long time, I need to get my data from the phone, but I can't unlock the phone because it apparently restarted after I dropped it and I can't use Touch ID. Touch screen is completely unresponsive.

Is there any way I can use Touch ID? I will then connect it to my computer and backup my photos.

Comment: If you connect it to a monitor and can see the iPhone's interface and touching the screen does not allow you to interact with what you are seeing on the monitor than it is  likely that you'll have to have the screen replaced to proceed.

Comment: In some cases it's enough to reconnect to flat cable of the display to the logic board. It really depends.

Comment: Could I do that at my own? I already sent it to service, but just wondering...